# One to many link table causing duplicate rows returned

Tags: php, mysql, relationship

Everything I've seen so far is about removing duplicate entries in a database automatically.  I want to stress at the beginning of this that **there is no duplicate data** in the database.  I'll also start with the fact that I'm very much still learning about RDBMS design, normalization, relationships, and, most of all, SQL!

I have a table of clients, with a clientid (PK) and a client_name.  I have a table of roles, with a roleid (PK) and a role_name.  Any client can have multiple roles associated with it.  So I created a client_role_link table, with clientid and roleid as the two fields.  Then I run this:

```
SELECT client.client_name, role.role_name FROM client 
  LEFT JOIN client_role_link ON client_role_link.clientid=client.clientid 
  LEFT JOIN role ON client_role_link.roleid=role.roleid 
  WHERE (role.roleid='1' OR role.roleid='2')
```

So let's say I have a client that has two roles associated with it (roles '1' and '2').  This query returns two rows, one for each role.  When I get these results back I'm using a `while` loop to cycle through the results and output them into a `<select>` list.  It's then causing two `<option>`'s with the same client listed.

I understand why my query is returning two rows, it makes sense.  So here comes the two fold question:

1. Is there a better database/table design that I should be using, or a more optimized query?
2. Or is this something I should handle in the PHP?  If so, is there a more elegant solution that adding all the results into an array, then looping back through the array and removing duplicates?

Thoughts?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the <select>? Do you want to output a list of all clients or a list of all roles? Or something else altogether?

Comment: I want to display only clients with particular roles and have them selectable.  I actually don't really need to pull the role name in this particular instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show both roles, then your query is `OK`.

`MySQL` does not support array datatypes, so you should fill an associative array on the `PHP` side using the resultset with the duplicate client names.

If you just need to show clients having either of the roles, use this query:

```
SELECT  c.*
FROM    client c
WHERE   c.clientid IN
        (
        SELECT  roleid
        FROM    client_role_link crl
        WHERE   crl.roleid IN (1, 2)
        )
```

This will return one record per client but won't show any roles.

The third way would implode the role names on the server side:

```
SELECT  c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(role_name SEPARATOR ';') AS roles
FROM    client c
LEFT JOIN
        client_role_link crl
ON      crl.clientid = c.clientid
        AND crl.roleid IN (1, 2)
LEFT JOIN
        role r
ON      r.roleid = crl.roleid
GROUP BY
        c.id
```

and explode them on `PHP` side, but make sure role names won't mix with the separator.

Comment: I think the first example is more along the lines of what I'm looking for, but I'm not too familiar with "IN" so I'll have to look that up.  I assume you're just running SQL against a generated dataset?  And yes, I know MySQL doesn't have arrays, I'm using mysqli and the fetch_assoc() method to get my data from the result set into a PHP array.  I just didn't want to have to loop back through that generated array and remove duplicates!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to get them back in array form.  Then you could have something like *code untested, but may work*:

```
$sql = "SELECT client.id, client.client_name, role.role_name FROM client LEFT JOIN client_role_link ON client_role_link.clientid=client.clientid LEFT JOIN role ON client_role_link.roleid=role.roleid WHERE (role.roleid='1' OR role.roleid='2')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$res = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $res[$row['id']]['roles'][] = $row['role_name'];
    $res[$row['id']]['client_name'] = $row['client_name']; //you'll be overwriting each iteration probably a better way
}
```

Comment: This is partially what I was trying to avoid, but is much cleaner than the solution I had come up with.